# Что из себя представляет null?

Tags: java, null, faq, java-faq

1. `null` - это экземпляр чего-то?
2. К какому типу принадлежит `null`?
3. Что такое `null`?
4. Как он представлен в памяти?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [«What is null in Java?»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2707322/1991579) от участника [@unj2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82368/unj2).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/2707322/1991579

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## `null` - это экземпляр чего-то?

Нет такого типа, которому бы соответствовал `instanceof` от `null`.

[15.20.2 Type Comparison Operator `instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)

> ```
> RelationalExpression:
>   RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType
> ```
>
> В рантайме результат оператора `instanceof` будет `true`, если
> значение *RelationalExpression* не `null` и ссылка может быть приведена
> к *ReferenceType* без получения исключения `ClassCastException`.
> Иначе результат будет `false`.

Это означает, что для любого типа `E` и `R`, для любого `E o`, где `o == null`, `o instanceof R` будет всегда `false`.

## К какому типу принадлежит `null`?

[JLS 4.1 The Kinds of Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1).

> Есть также специальный тип - *null*, тип выражения `null`,
> у которого нет имени. И т.к. тип *null* не имеет имени, невозможно объявить
> переменную с типом *null* или привести переменную к типу *null*.
> `null` ссылка - единственное возможное значение выражение типа *null*
> . `null` всегда можно привести к любому ссылочному типу. В
> действительности, можно игнорировать тип *null* и притвориться, что
> `null` - это просто специальный литерал, который может быть любым ссылочным типом.

## Что такое `null`?

Как сказано в цитате из JLS выше, можно считать, что "`null` - это просто специальный литерал, который может быть любым ссылочным типом".

В Java `null == null` (что верно не для всех языков). Из описания [`java.lang.Object`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> `public boolean equals(Object obj)`
>
> Для любой не `null` переменной `x`, `x.equals(null)` должен возвращать `false`.

`null` также является значением по умолчанию для всех ссылочных типов.

[JLS 4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> - Статические переменные класса, переменные экземпляра и массивы инициализируются значением по умолчанию при создании:
>   * Для всех ссылочных типов (§4.3), дефолтное значение - `null`.

Вы можете использовать это свойства для *отложенной инициализации*, когда поле будет иметь начальное значение `null` до тех пор, пока оно фактически не будет использовано, где будет заменено "реальным" значением (вычисление которого может быть дорогостоящим).

Есть и другие применения. Если посмотреть на [`java.lang.System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29):

> `public static Console console()`
>
> Returns: The system console, if any, otherwise null.

Это очень распространённая практика: `null` используется для обозначения несуществующего объекта.

Другой пример - [`java.io.BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

> `public String readLine() throws IOException`
>
> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
> stream has been reached.

`readLine()` будет возвращать `instanceof String` для каждой строки, пока не получит `null`, обозначающий конец. Это позволяет обрабатывать каждую строку следующим образом:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   process(line);
}
```

**Примечание:** пустая строка - не проблема, т.к. `"" != null`.

Давайте рассмотри [`java.util.Map<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29):

> `V get(Object key)`

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `null` if this map contains no mapping for the key.

> If this map permits `null` values, then a return value of `null` does not necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to `null`. The `containsKey` operation may be used to distinguish these two cases.

Здесь мы видим, что использование `null` может усложнить дело. Тут говорится, что, если такого ключа нет, будет возвращён `null`. Второе утверждение гласит, что даже если элемент по такому ключу есть, всё равно может вернуться `null`.

К примеру, [`java.util.Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) делает вещи проще путём запрета `null` в ключах и значениях; так что, если `V get(Object key)` вернёт `null` это однозначно говорит о том, что под таким ключом ничего нет.

Операции автоматического анбоксинга на `null` выбросят `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

```
Integer i = null;
     
// при анбоксинге null в integer будет выброшен NullPointerException 
int a = i;
```

Если резюмировать, то `null` используется как специальное значение для обозначения:

- Не инициализированного состояния.
- Терминальное условие
- Несуществующий объект.
- Неизвестное значение.

## Как `null` представлен в памяти?

Из [спецификации JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4):

> The Java Virtual Machine specification does not mandate a concrete
> value encoding `null`.

## Небольшое дополнение

Интересная цитата [C.A.R Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare):

> I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the
> `null` reference in 1965. At that time, I was designing the first
> comprehensive type system for references in an object oriented
> language ([ALGOL W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_W)). My goal was to ensure that all use of
> references should be absolutely safe, with checking performed
> automatically by the compiler. But I couldn't resist the temptation to
> put in a `null` reference, simply because it was so easy to implement.
> This has led to innumerable errors, vulnerabilities, and system
> crashes, which have probably caused a billion dollars of pain and
> damage in the last forty years.

Так же можно посмотреть [презентацию про ошибку на миллиард долларов](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare).

<sub>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос «What is null in Java?»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/1991579) от участника [@polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants).</sub>

Comment: И все же, хотелось бы увидеть конкретный ответ, как именно null представлен на низком уровне в наиболее распространенных реализациях

Comment: @avp надо будет на досуге почитать про это. Я с java уже много лет не работаю)