# Отличия ==, equals, null

Tags: java

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "a..b.c";
    String[] sentences = str.split("\\.");
    for (String i: sentences) {
        System.out.println(
                i + " " +
                (i == "") + " " +
                (i == null) + " " +
                (i.equals("")));
    }
}
}
//a false false false
// false false true
//b false false false
//c false false false
```

Почему у нас возникают отличия вывода во второй строке при "" и null от equals.
И почему при сравнении возникают false, если у нас вторая строка пустая?

Comment: [Как работает оператор проверки на равенство (оператор ==)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496080/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80), [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: [Что из себя представляет null?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871121/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-null)

Comment: https://tproger.ru/articles/9-things-about-null-in-java/ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java